# Run some code in the receiving app via Custom Url Scheme

Tags: ios, objective-c, url-scheme

I have an extension and a container app.I open the container app with the method

```
[[self extensionContext] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"customURLScheme://"] completionHandler:nil];
```

from extension via custom URL scheme but I don't know how to run some code in the container app as soon as it launches...??

In another words I'm trying to use the URL scheme just to open the app and then call some method from container app.

Answer (score 1):

In your containing app's `AppDelegate`, you need to implement the method `application:open:options:` and do whatever is required in there.

The containing app gets the full URL that was used to open it, so you can use the URL to encode different operations to perform.

Comment: Thanks but I've already done that but the code inside it doesn't get called.

Comment: Can you share the implementation from your `AppDelegate`?

Comment: Thanks Dave, turns out there is some kind of code that `application:openURL:options:` method can call and some can't.any way problem solved